# TranslateAnimation is not giving expected result

Tags: android, animation

I am new to animations in Android and have trouble understanding why the code below does not give the expected result.
I want to have the Button placed at absolute position (0,100) after sliding in from position outside of screen:

```
Button gift = new Button(this);

    gift.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    gift.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    gift.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);;

    gift.setTextSize(18);

    gift.setText(NSLocalizedString("BONUS!\nYou Found A Solution\nAnd I Didn't!\n"));

    int from []= new int [2];
    from[0]=-500;from[1]=100;

    int to []= new int [2];
    to[0]=0;to[1]=100;

    RelativeLayout journals = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    journals.addView(gift);

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, from[0],
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, from[1],
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, to[0],
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, to[1]
            );
    animation.setDuration(5000); // duartion in ms
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    gift.startAnimation(animation);
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure your relative layout is place at 0,0 and I think relative layout also demands some layout params, try linear layout

Comment: What is the issue? I can only guess from above that maybe the button isn't clickable, that is because you are using a view animation that doesn't actually move the button, just where it is drawn. You should try a property animation.

Comment: MY Activity uses RelativeLayout.
The button DOES move and stops at the position as shown in the screenshot.
I would like to stop it at (0,100). What can I do?

Comment: `why the code below does not give the expected result.` what is he doing instead? Is the picture you have added the expexted or the current result... Please be specific...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your layout xml file, place the button at the desired position which is according to you (0,100), using an AbsoluteLayout within RelativeLayout (use example here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_absolute_layout.htm).

Then, set button visibility to "**gone**" as button's property in your layout xml.

Now, do the following :

Add a file in your anim resource folder, name it slide_left.xml  :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <translate 
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXDelta="0%" 
    android:toXDelta="100%" 
    android:duration="1500"/>
 </set>
```

Then, change your code to :

```
...

// Your required button style :
Button gift = new Button(this);
gift.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
gift.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
gift.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);;
gift.setTextSize(18);
gift.setText(NSLocalizedString("BONUS!\nYou Found A Solution\nAnd I Didn't!\n"));
RelativeLayout journals = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
journals.addView(gift);


// Add these below lines : 
Animation slideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_left);
gift.startAnimation(slideLeft);
gift.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
...
```

Hope this solves your problem...